# Dual boot, I've not created the grub file on the 2nd OS

Tags: partition, grub2, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 14 and Windows 10 installed on the different partitions and working well.

I've created one more partition and installed Arch into it. Actually, I made only the 1st part of installation which was copying files to that separate partition and it should be enough for now as it'd already allow me to boot the Arch.

Now, when I was installing Arch, I've not made any operations involving grub at all. I've not created the grub file and haven't called "grub-install". I thought the grub from Ubuntu would do all necessary stuff afterwards. And it'll probably will.

So how do I make the grub from Ubuntu find the Arch I've installed? Should I use "boot-repair"? I've tried, though, but it said I'd have to do that from the live CD.

And was not calling "grub" from Arch a right thing to do?

Comment: I think a simple "sudo update-grub" from Ubuntu should find Arch.

Comment: @no_choice99, I've done that, can I verify the result without reboot?

Comment: Yes you can. With the output of the command, if you see something related to Arch then the job is done.

Comment: @no_choice99, it's working, but now it says "ready only file system" whenever I try to create a file whether I be a normal user or admin (sudo). How to fix it?

Comment: check out https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133376.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you if use the grub customizer  if you install is a light and good tool in aid of the grub configuration with many systems to start.